# Hide data for each others in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula, privacy, importrange

I have a spreadsheet which is shared among 100 users, The users enter data in a timely fashion.
I want  to make sure that the user is able to see only the data entered by him and not anyone else.
How can I achieve this in Google Sheets.

Other ideas are open, but not sure if that will be in my skill set to implement

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad for this site. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

the only possible way is to set up multiple spreadsheets and give away 1 spreadsheet to each of your people. then have a master sheet where you import all the data in one place. this way each person will see only his/her own sheet and you will have access to all data across all the sheets from your people. fx to import stuff is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_ID_or_URL", "sheetname_here!A1:C30")
```